# AWS Admin Account but can't see billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

I have created my own AWS Admin (root) account. The problem is I can't see the billing breakdown in the billing section. It's been a long time since I've been using it and I can remember that I can see it before. Wonder why I can't see it now? the only difference between now and then is before there were no IAM users, only admin. Now I have created one.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you referring to an IAM user with Admin role/policy attached? I know billing doesn't show up with this configuration, and I have to login as as root/email for billing. There's a way to allow for IAM access to billing but requires activating: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/control-access-billing.html#ControllingAccessWebsite-Activate

Comment: I am already using the root account @peter n

Comment: If your root account can't properly access the billing section, you should open a support case with AWS.